# Cannot pass more parameters in passport.js - MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, passport.js, mean-stack, mean

Hello so I have the following code in my passport.js:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    nameField: 'fullname',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done, fullname) {

    // asynchronous
    // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
    process.nextTick(function() {

    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // check to see if theres already a user with that email
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
        } else {

            // if there is no user with that email
            // create the user
            var newUser            = new User();

            // set the user's local credentials
            newUser.local.email    = email;
            newUser.local.password = password;
            newUser.local.fullname = fullname;
            newUser.local.role = "default";

            // save the user
            newUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                } 
                console.log(newUser);
                return done(null, newUser);

            });
        }

    });    

    });

}));
```

And I need to save the fullname into the database but unfortunately doesn't add because is the last parameter, after done. But if ill put fullname before done, the return done is is not found and gives me a application crash.

What do you think can be a solution?

Comment: can't you just get the fullname (nameField) from the `req` param?

Comment: No, I cannot, i just tried that.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the fullname from the `req` param. If you are using `bodyparser` then it is as simple as `req.body.fullname`. Use that where you need it. You need to make sure you are sending the `fullname` from the form with the email and password.

Local strategy for passport doesn't support other inputs than the `usernameField` and `passwordField`. If you need other inputs from the user you need to retrieve them from the original request.